# why running android 2.3.4 and android 1.6 emulator throw different exception?

Tags: java, android

I test some code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Fragment f = new Fragment();

}
```

I usd sdk4.0 compile, and AndroidManifest.xml use-sdk minSdk=4 targetSdkVersion=14

When I run it on android 1.6 emulator it throw **java.lang.VerifyError**, but on phone running android 2.3.4 it throws **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError**.

Why??

I do not need Fragment class, I just test a Class that include android 3.0 sdk. I just want to see what will print.

java.lang.VerifyError（Thrown when the VM notices that an attempt is made to load a class which does not pass the class verification phase.）

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
（Thrown when the VM is unable to locate a class which it has been asked to load.）

They both extend LinkageError，LinkageError is the superclass of all error classes that occur when loading and linking class files.

I found this in dalvik docs

> Verification Failures
>
> The verifier may reject a class immediately, or it may defer throwing
>   an exception until the code is actually used. For example, if a class
>   attempts to perform an illegal access on a field, the VM should throw
>   an IllegalAccessError the first time the instruction is encountered.
>   On the other hand, if a class contains an invalid bytecode, it should
>   be rejected immediately with a VerifyError.
>
> Immediate VerifyErrors are accompanied by detailed, if somewhat
>   cryptic, information in the log file. From this it's possible to
>   determine the exact instruction that failed, and the reason for the
>   failure.
>
> It's a bit tricky to implement deferred verification errors in Dalvik.
>   A few approaches were considered:
>
> We could replace the invalid field access instruction with a special
>   instruction that generates an illegal access error, and allow class
>   verification to complete successfully. This type of verification must
>   be deferred to first class load, rather than be performed ahead of
>   time during DEX optimization, because some failures will depend on the
>   current execution environment (e.g. not all classes are available at
>   dexopt time). At that point the bytecode instructions are mapped
>   read-only during verification, so rewriting them isn't possible. We
>   can perform the access checks when the field/method/class is resolved.
>   In a typical VM implementation we would do the check when the entry is
>   resolved in the context of the current classfile, but our DEX files
>   combine multiple classfiles together, merging the field/method/class
>   resolution results into a single large table. Once one class
>   successfully resolves the field, every other class in the same DEX
>   file would be able to access the field. This is incorrect. Perform the
>   access checks on every field/method/class access. This adds
>   significant overhead. This is mitigated somewhat by the DEX optimizer,
>   which will convert many field/method/class accesses into a simpler
>   form after performing the access check. However, not all accesses can
>   be optimized (e.g. accesses to classes unknown at dexopt time), and we
>   don't currently have an optimized form of certain instructions
>   (notably static field operations). In early versions of Dalvik (as
>   found in Android 1.6 and earlier), the verifier simply regarded all
>   problems as immediately fatal. This generally worked, but in some
>   cases the VM was rejecting classes because of bits of code that were
>   never used. The VerifyError itself was sometimes difficult to
>   decipher, because it was thrown during verification rather than at the
>   point where the problem was first noticed during execution.
>
> The current version uses a variation of approach #1. The dexopt
>   command works the way it did before, leaving the code untouched and
>   flagging fully-correct classes as "pre-verified". When the VM loads a
>   class that didn't pass pre-verification, the verifier is invoked. If a
>   "deferrable" problem is detected, a modifiable copy of the
>   instructions in the problematic method is made. In that copy, the
>   troubled instruction is replaced with an "always throw" opcode, and
>   verification continues.

Comment: Likely the JRE is different between the two devices, which causes issues in the same way it does on a desktop (when trying to run a class not compiled for your JRE).

Comment: as jli said, it's just the two different versions of JRE (probably). But regardless, I believe Fragments were introduced 3.0, though so that functionality can't be in 1.6 or 2.3.4. If you need Fragments, then you can do conditional class loading based on the value returned from `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`

Comment: I do not need Fragment class, I just test a Class that include android 3.0 sdk. I just want to see what will print.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be in x:\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v4 find android-support-v4. Jar added to the project.

In the project

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Comment: I do not need Fragment class, I just test a Class that include android 3.0 sdk. I just want to see what will print.